# How to create and PDF Form in form of table using Apache PDFBOX library?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to create an PDF Form containing table where table will be having number of rows and some columns will be read only Text whereas some of the columns are needed to be TextFields/ComboBox which are editable.

Also this Textfields/Combobox should have javascript support, i.e, on value change of these fields, javascript function should be invoked for validation of user input.

I have attached sample format required here:

[image]